# Why i get this error with Woocommerce REST API

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

i need some help. I'm trying to add a composite product via REST API. The problem is that i keep getting the same error:

```
{"code": "woocommerce_rest_invalid_component_data",
"message": "Invalid data - No component options found.",
"data": {
    "status": 400
}
```

}

The link im trying to POST it to: https://www.prinshoutkopen.nl/wp-json/wc/v3/products

My JSON code:

```
   { "name": "Build Your Ninja Outfit",
    "type": "composite",
    "description": "In pretium enim justo, at ornare libero aliquam quis. Nullam imperdiet rutrum volutpat. Suspendisse aliquet ex in ex volutpat vestibulum. Curabitur ultrices convallis condimentum.",
    "short_description": "In pretium enim justo, at ornare libero aliquam quis.",
    "composite_layout": "single",
    "composite_components": [{
        "title": "Your Ninja Tee",
            "description": "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.",
            "query_type": "category_ids",
            "query_ids": [ 14 ],
            "quantity_min": 1,
            "quantity_max": 1,
            "priced_individually": true,
            "shipped_individually": false,
            "optional": false,
            "discount": "20.0",
            "options_style": "thumbnails"
    }]
}
```

I also tried via CURL but i recieved the same error code.

Answer (score 0):

**you should create post with this options:**

```js
const data = {
  name: "Premium Quality",
  type: "simple",
  regular_price: "21.99",
  description: "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.",
  short_description: "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.",
  categories: [
    {
      id: 9
    },
    {
      id: 14
    }
  ],
  images: [
    {
      src: "http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg"
    },
    {
      src: "http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_back.jpg"
    }
  ]
};
```

see here:
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).